# My 2-year-old son is crying at midnight and keeps crying every five minutes till early morning

Tags: toddler, sleep, crying

For the past three days my 2-year-old boy keeps crying at midnight till early morning 6 or 7 am every five minutes and not opening his eyes.

We were really worried what could be the reason. He keeps asking

1. Water
2. Milk
3. All the animals toys

But he never satisfied with any of the above. We checked his temperature, everything seems to be normal but we couldn't find the reason why.

What are some things we can do to try and comfort him and get him to return to sleep or help find an underlying reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe explore with him other possible issues? I can think of:

- Scared of dark. (can be easily fixed with a night-light)
- Scared of the silence. (some white noise?)
- Scared of dreams and nightmares.

I'm not entirely sure, but I think it's around that age that dreams and nightmares can start. It can be really upsetting when you don't even know the concept of dreams. If that is the issue, I think there are ressources online about stuff to try to deal with nightmares.

I know my daughter went quite easily through the nightmares phase. We started by asking her if she was having dreams and nightmares, explaining what dreams are in the first place, to give her a word for what might be happening. And for nightmares, the solutions that suited her that we found at that time was to draw the monster that she dreamed about.

Comment: We have used some combination of night light, white noise, and comforting when we think its a night terror as around 2 or 3 those can start. Its been effective for us.

Comment: We have tried your approach yesterday. He started feeling better. Thank you..